# String Manipulation in SQL Server (STRING_SPLIT, REVERSE)

Tags: sql-server

I want to reverse the sub-strings in `NVARCHAR` column, that are separated by one character like '-', for example:

Input column cl:

`a1-b1-c1-d1`

Required output:

`d1-c1-b1-a1`

I tried `REVERSE(cl)`, the result was `1d-1c-1b-1a`!

The best approach I think is using:

```
STRING_SPLIT(cl,'-')
```

And then looking for reversing the resulted sub strings and rejoining them, but since we don't know how many delimited sub strings, it is still difficult to handle.

How can we achieve this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REVERSE` isn't what you are after here. What you are after is a string splitter that supports (is aware of) ordinal positions; `STRING_SPLIT` is documented that it explicitly "doesn't care" about the ordinal positions of values in a delimited string.

One function that *is* aware of ordinal positions is [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2). You can then use that, along with `STRING_AGG` to recreate your delimited string:

```sql
SELECT STRING_AGG(DS.item,'-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber DESC) AS R
FROM (VALUES('a1-b1-c1-d1'))V(S)
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(V.S,'-') DS;
```

Of course, the *real* solution here is to stop storing delimited data in your database in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for this cleaner solution, but I am getting `Invalid object name dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`! and still do not see where to fit the column, for example what is V(S) and V.S?

Comment: An UDF (string splitter with ordinal positions) is a possible option, +1.

Comment: @TiyebM If you are getting *"Invalid object name dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD"* you haven't created the function (in the database you are connected to).

Answer (score 3):

If using an UDF is not an option, you may try a JSON-based approach. You need to transform the input values into a valid JSON array (`a1-b1-c1-d1` into `["a1", "b1","c1","d1"]`) and parse this array with `OPENJSON()`:

```
CREATE TABLE Data (ColumnData nvarchar(max))
INSERT INTo Data (ColumnData) VALUES (N'a1-b1-c1-d1')

UPDATE Data
SET ColumnData = (
   SELECT STRING_AGG([value], N'-') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY CONVERT(int, [key]) DESC)
   FROM OPENJSON(CONCAT(N'["', REPLACE(STRING_ESCAPE(ColumnData, 'json'), N'-', '","'), '"]'))
)
```

Result:

```
ColumnData
-----------
d1-c1-b1-a1
```

Comment: Thank you, here I get,  `Invalid object name 'OPENJSON'`.

Comment: @TiyebM `OPENJSON()` is available from SQL Server 2016 (as `STRING_SPLIT()`). What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: OK, I see, it is 2017.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a modern version of SQL Server (2016 or higher), you can do it as you said: you split the string with string_split, you reverse its order, and aggregate the result with string_agg.

```
with cte as (
  select value, 
         row_number() over (order by (select null)) as number 
         from string_split('a1-b1-c1-d1', '-')
)
select string_agg(value, '-') within group (order by number desc)
from cte
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer, and as the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) says: *"The order of the output may vary as the order is not guaranteed to match the order of the substrings in the input string."* Be *very* careful with this approach, it has no guarantee of being correct.

Answer (score 1):

This splits the string while preserving the ordinal position without using a custom splitter.  To preserve the ordering of words the CHARINDEX function is used as per [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/207274/string-split-and-ordered-results/233480).

```
declare
  @string               nvarchar(4000)='a1-b1-c1-d1',
  @added_delimitter     CHAR(1)= '-';

;with ndx_split_cte(split_val, split_ndx) as (
    select
      sp.[value],
      CHARINDEX(@added_delimitter + sp.[value] + @added_delimitter, @added_delimitter + @string + @added_delimitter)
    from
      string_split(@string, '-') sp)
select string_agg(split_val, '-') within group (order by split_ndx desc) rev_split_str
from ndx_split_cte;
```

Results

```
rev_split_str
d1-c1-b1-a1
```